# IPv6 decoder for pcapy/impacket

Tags: python, ipv6, packet-capture, impacket, pcapy

I use the [pcapy](http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html)/[impacket](http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/impacket.html) library to decode network packets in Python. It has an IP decoder which knows about the syntax of IPv4 packets but apparently no IPv6 decoder.

Does anyone get one?

In a private correspondance, the Impacket maintainers say it may be better to start with [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

Comment: It looks like IPv6 has been added to impacket: http://code.google.com/p/impacket/downloads/detail?name=impacket-0.9.9.9.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2):

Scapy, recommended by the Impacket maintainers, has no IPv6 decoding at this time. But there is an [unofficial extension](http://namabiiru.hongo.wide.ad.jp/scapy6/) to do so.

With this extension, it works:

```
for packet in traffic:
  if packet.type == ETH_P_IPV6 or packet.type == ETH_P_IP:
    ip = packet.payload
    if (ip.version == 4 and ip.proto == UDP_PROTO) or \
       (ip.version == 6 and ip.nh == UDP_PROTO):
        if ip.dport == DNS_PORT and ip.dst == ns:
            all_queries = all_queries + 1
```

but it is awfully slow for large traces. So, I may have to try Impacket nevertheless or even go back to C.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [`dpkt`](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/), yet another packet parsing/building library.  It was written by the author of [`pypcap`](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/), a different libpcap wrapper, but it shouldn't be too difficult to get it working with pcapy to see if it's faster for your purposes than Scapy.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used pcapy before, but I do have used libpcap in C projects. As the pcapy page states it is not statically linked to libcap, so you can upgrade to a newer one with IPv6 support.

According to [libpcap changelog](http://www.tcpdump.org/libpcap-changes.txt), version 1.0 released on October 27, 2008, has default IPv6 support (it is supposed to have IPv6 from much longer but it is now default compiled with that option), so you should be able to capture IPv6 traffic with this version. Latest pcapy release is from March 27, 2007, so at most it should include a 0.9.8 version of libcap released on September 10, 2007.

I don't know if that would be enough for you to be able to capture IPv6 traffic since pcapy API would probably requiere some changes to support it, and that's on pcapy developer's roof.

**Update**: Apparently [pylibpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap), a python wrapper to libpcap, has newer releases than pcapy, so newer libpcap features should be better supported.

More information about PCAP (libpcap) in general [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap).

Comment: I was not talking about the *capture* of IPv6 packets (something that libpcap does for a very long time) but about their decoding. libpcap does not decode, you have to do it yourself with low-level C tricks. pcapy comes with decoders.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a really useful one-file library from google from

http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/

that supports IPv4, IPv6, ip validation, netmask and prefix managements, etc. It's well coded and documented.

Good luck
Emilio

Comment: this can be done on Ubuntu by `apt-get install python-ipaddr`